# Stacked Bar Chart (High charts) in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular JS, I was using High charts for building Pie charts and Stacked Bar charts. Now, we want to switch to AngularJS. Is it possible to build Stacked Bar Chart using angular and high charts APIs.
 Do i need to use JQuery inside angular to build high charts? Is it the only approach?

Comment: When you use highchart it realy does not matter if you use jquery or not. You can always wrap it in your own directive or you can use one of the open source wrappers for highchart https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: @PSL I am still new to Angular, but i was able to plot the High chart using Custom Directive. Now, I want that data for High Chart should come from a Rest Service but I am getting this data inside Controller function but since it is an Async call the data is undefined and link function is getting called, what will be the best way to achieve this? Should i go for Synchronous calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch to angularjs, it is best to change your jQuery habits and think 'the angular way', which will come with practice.

Regarding pie charts, angularjs goes well with D3.js:

[Blog on angularjs combined with D3.js](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html)

So, to answer your question:

> Is it possible to build Stacked Bar Chart using angular and high charts APIs

Anything is possible, but as angularjs and D3.js go well together, and are both well documented, you are probably better off going for angularjs + D3. There even is a book on the subject: [see this post for more information](https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3-resources/d3-and-angular)

Both angularjs and D3 use json and go well with REST APIs, so the actual fetching of data from the server should be a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Use highcharts-ng: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

It is a wrapper for using Highcharts APIs in Angular JS.